# Count depth in recursion

Tags: java

We have some link on input :
 "http://test.com" this link has links : 
 "http://test.com", "http://test.com/some", "http://google.com" 
 and "http://test.com/some" has links : "http://facebook.com", "some.com"

Needed result is : 
 Steps to main : 0 Link : "http://test.com" ExtLinksCount : 1

Steps to main : 1 Link : "http://test.com/some" ExtLinksCount : 2

I counted the extlinks, but i don't know how to count step in recursion

```
public void info(String url) throws IOException {

        if (!parsedLinks.contains(url)) {

            parsedLinks.add(url);
            String[] links =  hp.getLinks(url);
            System.out.println("Link : " + url + "\n"
                              +"ExtLinksCount : " + externalLinksCount(links) + "\n"
                              +"Steps to main : " + step
                              );
            String strippedLink;

            for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

                strippedLink = LinkParser.parseLink(links[i]);

                if ( strippedLink.contains(this.baseUrl) ) {
                    ++ step; 
                    info(links[i]);
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a variable "step" to your constructor. You already have the code to increment it.

Comment: I already have this variable in the counstructor. But it doesn't count depth, because it works only on one branch of recursion

Comment: I have no idea how to count it on all branches of recursion

Comment: @incredible_titan I think what @hatcyl meant was to make `step` a parameter of the method and to increase it in each recursive call: `public void info(String url, int step) { [...] info(link, step+1); [...]}`. If `step` is defined outside of `info` it will count the *accumulated* steps instead. But note that while will accurately measure the depth of recursion, it will not necessarily get you the lowest number of steps to reach some URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the number of steps required to reach some URL starting from your 'main' URL, keeping track of the depth will not always get you the desired result, since the recursive implementation behaves like a depth-first search.

Consider the following graph: `A -> [B, C]; B -> [C]`. Calling `info(A)` you will iterate over the links to B and C. First, you call `info(B)`, setting the distance (A, B) to 1. Now, from the call to `info(B)`, you call `info(C)`, setting the distance (A, C) to 2. `info(C)` and `info(B)` return, and you call `info(C)` again, this time from `info(A)`, but this call immediately returns without updating the distance (A, C) to 1, because C is already in the set of parsed links.

Using recursion, you could try something like this (pseudocode):

```
info(url):
    for link in links(url):
        if link not in visited or visited[link] > visited[url] + 1:
            visited[link] = visited[url] + 1
            info(link)
```

where `visited` is a map, mapping URLs to their distance from the main URL, being initialized so that `visited[main] = 0`. However, this will still visit some links multiple times, so it would be more efficient to use a breadth-first search:

```
info(main):
    visited = map{main: 0}
    queue = queue(main)
    while queue not empty:
        url = queue.pop()
        for link in links(url):
            if link not in visited:
                visited[link] = visited[url] + 1
                queue.append(link)
```